# spring cloud stream kafka 2.0 - StreamListener with condition

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a consumer using StreamListener annotation and condition attirbute.However , i'm getting the following exception :

org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'test'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test"

**TestListener:**

```
@StreamListener(target=ITestSink.CHANNEL_NAME,condition="payload['test'] == 'test'")
public void test(@Payload TestObj message) {
    log.info("message is {}",message.getName());
}
```

**TestObj:**

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper=true)
public class TestObj {

    @JsonProperty("test")
    private String test;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

}
```

can someone assist with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

the payload of the message is not yet converted from the wire format (byte[]) to the desired type. In other words, it has not yet gone through the type conversion process described in the Content Type Negotiation.

So, unless you use a SPeL expression that evaluates raw data (for example, the value of the first byte in the byte array), use message header-based expressions (such as condition = "headers['type']=='dog'").

Example:

```
 @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='bogey'")
    public void receiveBogey(@Payload BogeyPojo bogeyPojo) {
       // handle the message
    }
```

Check the Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_programming_model.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing).

Answer (score 0):

From what you show, it should work. I suggest you remove the condition, then set breakpoint to debug. Then you should be able to know which actual type is.